# How to create index of value in results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table of values:

```
date     |  number
--------------------
01012015 |  123450
01012015 |  123450
01012015 |  123450
01012015 |  123450
01012015 |  123451
01012015 |  123451
01012015 |  123451
01012015 |  123452
01012015 |  123452
01012015 |  123453
01012015 |  123453
01012015 |  123454
01012015 |  123454
```

and I wanted to report to a select value of position in search results, thus creating an index in sql server.

```
date     | number   | index
----------------------------
01012015 |  123450  |  1
01012015 |  123450  |  2
01012015 |  123450  |  3 
01012015 |  123450  |  4
01012015 |  123451  |  1
01012015 |  123451  |  2
01012015 |  123451  |  3
01012015 |  123452  |  1
01012015 |  123452  |  2
01012015 |  123453  |  1
01012015 |  123453  |  2
01012015 |  123454  |  1
01012015 |  123454  |  2
```

any ideia?

**OBS: without using views.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

```
SELECT
    date,
    number,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY date, number ORDER BY number DESC) AS index
FROM
    myTable;
```